# How to manage User Stories that take more than one Sprint

Tags: agile, scrum

I'm working on a software product that is content heavy.  The problem is that a feature often requires new content, and content production for us takes longer than a sprint or takes more than half a sprint.

For example, one feature might require us to film 100 different short videos (2-3 seconds) and go through post-production.  To film the videos requires travel time, etc.  Even if I broke out the feature into 100 stories, one for each video, the content is still going to require a lot of time because it's not going to be filmed one by one and edited one by one.

Could I have the same story throughout subsequent sprints, with different acceptance criteria?  For example the story would be "As a User I want to see blah blah videos so that I can blah blah".  Then in one Sprint the AC would be to film the videos.  The next sprint I would have another user story (different ID), with the same text, but the AC might be to "integrate the videos into the app"?  Not sure if that violates Scrum doctrine.

Has anyone run into a similar situation?  How is this handled in a Scrum environment?

Comment: Pipelining tasks is common. Having multiple tasks per user story is also common.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it sounds like you're trying to use Scrum to drive a production line, which is absolutely the wrong tool for the job. It sounds like you know exactly what you need to shoot and produce, so no learning is occurring (which is fine if you don't need it). To illustrate, let's create an example where scrum would be ideally suited:

Let's say you run a marketing web page for a popular brand and they want to run a new campaign this season. They want to do something with "getting back to nature" and you have a few ideas. You would have to shoot tons of videos to replace the ones on the site, but you don't want to shoot 100 new videos only to have the client unhappy with them. So, you take 3 major ideas and you change one page requires you to shoot and edit 4 videos for each idea. You do 2 of them in the sprint and maybe pitch the third because it's going to be more involved - you have to travel to Thailand to get the footage. If they like one of the first two, you go with that for the whole site. Otherwise you invest in the proof of concept for the third.

Here, it's all about confirming your assumptions before you invest too much, and then Scrum makes sense. If you're just producing a ton of videos though, I'm not sure why you would try to force the use of Scrum.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your ticket into sub tickets like 10 video shootings and editing. Or you can prolong your sprint period according to your needs. Another approach can be switching to kanban.